# What is the general word for a religious ceremony or observation?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, religio

Suppose I wish to talk about the various aspects of Roman religion: prayers, festivals, sacrifices, and everything else. In English, "observances" is a fairly general term for all of these aspects together.

Is there an equivalent term in Latin? I'm mostly interested in the official religion of the (pre-Constantine) state, so whether or not the term includes things like mystery cults and Christian practices doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *De Civitate Dei*, Augustine quotes Varro, who was the author of *Antiquitates rerum divinarum*. The latter was making distinctions between the various conceptions of the Roman gods. Concerning the third *genus* of these conceptions, he says:

> Tertium genus est [...] quod in urbibus cives, maxime sacerdotes,
>   nosse atque administrare debent. In quo est, quos deos publice sacra
>   ac sacrificia colere et facere quemque par sit. (Varro, cf. *De
>   Civitate Dei* vi, ch. 5)

Of particular interest is his use of the word *sacra.* Among the definitions for ***sacrum*** given by [Lewis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sacra&la=la#lexicon) is the following:

> A sacred act, religious rite, act of worship, sacrifice, religious
>   service

Answer (score 4):

Like English, Latin has words for particular ceremonies, but unlike English, it does actually have a general word, **caerimonia**, which is used for sacred ceremonies (but not for profane usages). Another word, *ritus*, is more general and may be used for both sacred and profane.